# Identification of $H^2(End^0(E))$ and $Ext^2(E,E)_0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $H$ be a smooth hyperplane section of $X$. Let $E$ be a rank $r$ vector bundle on $X$ which is slope stable with respect to $H$. Then let $End^0(E)$ be the kernel of the trace map $End(E) \to \mathcal O_X$.

One also have an induced map say $tr^i$ from $Ext^i(E,E) \cong H^i(End(E)) \to H^i(\mathcal O_X)$.

Is it true that for $i=2$, $\text{kernel}(tr^2)=H^2(End^0(E))$?

Is this true because of something obvious (e.g something along the lines of $H^i$ commutes with taking kernel)?

Comment: Cohomology does not commute with taking kernel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If characteristic of the base field is coprime to the rank of $E$, the trace map is a split epimorphism. Indeed, the composition
$$
\mathcal{O}_X \stackrel{\mathrm{id}}\to 
\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}(E) \stackrel{\mathrm{tr}}\to 
\mathcal{O}_X
$$
is the multiplication by the rank of $E$. Thus,
$$
\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}(E) \cong 
\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}^0(E) \oplus \mathcal{O}_X,
$$
hence the cohomology long exact sequence splits as well.

Comment: @ Sasha, I knew this relation $\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}(E) \cong 
\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}^0(E) \oplus \mathcal{O}_X$, and from there we can have,  $H^2(\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}(E)) \cong 
H^2(\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}^0(E)) \oplus H^2(\mathcal{O}_X)$. Now by the splitting long exact cohomology sequence, do you mean that one can write, $H^2(\mathcal{E}\mathit{nd}(E)) \cong 
\text{kernel}(tr^2) \oplus H^2(\mathcal{O}_X)$ and hence by comparison we have the identification. Please let me know if you meant something otherwise.

Comment: Yes, this is right.